# How to load global settings frequently used in application in Java

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, ehcache

1) In my application we have a table which stores some settings detail which are used heavily for every functionality.Basically some conditions are set up in this table which are checked.

Now currently what we are doing is making DB call every now and then to fetch the details and check the condition.This has resulted in lot of DB calls and repetitive calls for the same condition.There are quite a lot of condition records in this table.We need to change this to make it perform better.

2) In my previous project also i had same requirement where we have a configuration table where such settings are configured,there we implemented it like load the configuration from table at start up of application and store them in System.setProperty(name,value)..and later use System.getProperty(name) to retrieve it.In case any settings is changed we update this in its System property.This worked like a charm.

However,in my current case(point 1 above) I don't think my prev way is best way to do it because lot of records present in the table having lot of columns.
Can anyone suggest a way how to achieve such kind of behavior in Java? Some of them I can think of is

1) Using System.setProperty like I explained.
2) Using caching like EHCache - standalone or with hibernate(as we are using hibernate).

Any better way to store such global settings of application so as to avoid DB calls?

Comment: Research the `Properties` class and its methods.

Comment: `Map<String, String>`?

Comment: @David- Thanks for the response but I guess Properties class won't help here much.

Comment: I don't see why not.  It's what I always use to solve exactly the problem you've described.  But this is your application, so you know best.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do it using Ehcache(but I have never implemented it). And you should not play with System property it may cause conflict with other system properties.
How I did it in my case I have created a bean class which is having properties as yor table column like autoid, name, address, mobile.

```
public Map<Integer, PersonBean> getTag()
{
     Map<Integer, PersonBean> map= new HashMap<Integer, PersonBean>();
     Connection conn =getConnection();
     Statement st=null;
     ResultSet rs=null;
    try
    {
        String sql = "select autoid,name, address, mobile from person";//person table
         st =  conn.createStatement();


         rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next()){
            int tagid=rs.getInt("autoid");
            String name=rs.getString("name");
            String address=rs.getString("address");
            String mobile=rs.getString("mobile");
            PersonBean tagdeatilbean= new PersonBean(auotoid,name, address, mobile);
            map.put(rs.getInt("autoid"), tagdeatilbean);
        }
        return map;
    }

     catch (SQLException e) {

    }
    finally
    {

    }
}
```

and bean class

```
public class PersonBean 
{
    private int autoid;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String mobile;
    public PersonBean(int autoid, String name, String address, String mobile)
    {
    this.autoid=autoid;
    .....
    ....
    }

    //setter
    //getter
}
```

If this is web application then you can load this cache map in init method and call the value according to autuid of row from map.

Comment: Thanks for the response but is Ehcache have any usecase which implements this functionality because I am little doubtful whether its ok to refresh cache from time to time.And for code you posted I have to make it static somehow to have loaded it once like init you told and make it available.

Comment: I have no idea about Ehcache. And yes you have use static map..and if you want to update the cache then put this  this static map inside doPost or doGet method too like this `if("updatecache".equals(request.getParameter("cacheupadte"){ map= getTag();}` and remaining logic in else block. In this case you have to fire a seperate url to update cache without application restart. But if you are worry about Thread safety then things will little complicated.

Comment: But don't you think this is very common functionality for enterprise applications and there is some standard way of achieving this.

Comment: Yes i do think so but the same way I can't implement third party api without management's concern. There is very long process to get this kind of permission and they won't approve it until some proper acknowledge from clients and all. I'm lobbying for this very hard. Till then I will stick with this. If you have better native idea you can share it with me.